# The 'Content-Type' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method. Parameter name: name

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

Hi I am using HttpWebRequest GET method to call a REST service.  I am getting error :- ***'Content-Type' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method. Parameter name: name.***i checked all answer related this issue from stackoverflow.

My Code:-

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Getvalue(TextBox1.Text,TextBox2.Text,TextBox3.Text);
    }

    private void Getvalue(string text1, string text2, string text3)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.ContentType = "appication/json";
        request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "appication/json");
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        string myResponse = "";
 using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new system.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            myResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Response.Write(myResponse);

}
}
```

Comment: Well why are you setting the `ContentType` property and then *also* trying to set it in the headers? Just remove that `request.Headers.Add` line - setting the property should be all you need. Note that it's more useful if you provide real code - the code you've given at the moment wouldn't compile.

Comment: You also want application/json, not appication/json.

Comment: Sorry..! Not using  GET method to call a REST service. Using POST method to call rest service

Comment: What difference does that make?

Comment: OK, Jon i changed  in code what ever you mention , now i getting other error :  The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: Well have you fixed the typo of appication/json to application/json? Have you looked at what the request looks like on the network? Note that you're not actually specifying any content at the moment...

Comment: yes i have fixed it application/json , now  I getting  error:(400) Bad Request

Comment: Right, and do you know what the request is *meant* to look like? Again, it's odd to specify a content type but not provide any actual content. I suggest you use something like Postman to get a *working* request, and then try to mimic that in C#. I suggest you close this question, as it's no longer the problem you reported.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I too ended up with this problem. But realized the issue is with how you setting the content type.

The proper way to set is

```
request.ContentType = "application/json";
```